# Bash - Hex to String

Tags: bash

In bash, how can I convert an hex-encoded string like this:

```
2e2f65202d6b2022616622
```

or

```
\x2e\x2f\x65\x20\x2d\x6b\x20\x22\x61\x66\x22
```

(or something similiar) to:

```
./e -k "af"
```

... and then execute it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval `printf "\x2e\x2f\x65\x20\x2d\x6b\x20\x22\x61\x66\x22"`
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way I can think of to do this would be through a function.

For example:

```
exec_hex_str() {
    cmd_val=$(printf "$1")
    echo "Executing: $cmd_val"
    eval $cmd_val
}
```