# How to use ANSI-C Quoting with Shell variables?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, encoding, busybox

I have a sed command with hex replacement, which i used in Busybox: ( `BusyBox v1.32.1 (2022-03-05 22:56:19 CET) multi-call binary.`)

This works on other Linux environments:

```
HEXCODE=34
sed "s/\xa1\xb2/\x12\x$HEXCODE/g" < file.bin > file2.bin
```

On my busybox sed environment it doesn't.

This works fine with Ansi Encoding string:

This works:

```
sed $'s/\xa1\xb2/\x12\x34/g' < file.bin > file2.bin
```

But i want this here with Shell variable use:

```
HEXCODE=34
sed $'s/\xa1\xb2/\x12\x$HEXCODE/g' < file.bin > file2.bin
```

This doen't work for me, so can I get some help here?

**Edit:**

pynexj's tipps helps here with eval / printf:
Just need this oneliner here:

But i want this here with Shell variable use:

```
HEXCODE=34
eval sed "\$'s/\xa1\xb2/\x12\x$HEXCODE/g'" < file.bin > file2.bin
```

Comment: In your second version, the single quotes forbid variable expansion. You need use double quotes, but this does not work together with the `\x` in front of the variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash - Hex to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884388/bash-hex-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` or `eval`. See the following example:

```
[bash-5.1] $ cat foo.sh
s='hello world'

HEX=4c  # 'L'

# use `printf'
cmd=$( printf "s/l/\x$HEX/g" )
echo "$s" | busybox sed -e "$cmd"

# use `eval'
eval cmd="\$'s/l/\x$HEX/g' "
echo "$s" | busybox sed -e "$cmd"
[bash-5.1] $ busybox sh foo.sh
heLLo worLd
heLLo worLd
```

Comment: Thanks, eval / printf works for me here, so I will edit my First Post with my example.